# How to send a variable from ajax success to a template?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Is it possible reload a page without refresh (silently) ? 
[Here](http://www.espncricinfo.com/icc_cricket_worldcup2011/engine/current/match/433560.html) is an example where page reload automatically. But you can easily see that the page is refreshing after certain time interval. I don't like this where end user is getting such experience. I want that the page reload but without refreshing. End user should not feel that page is refreshing. Is it possible using simple html? or jquery?

I don't want `<META HTTP-EQUIV="refresh" CONTENT="5">`  or `setTimeout` of jquery because it refreshes the page while reloading?

Answer (score 0):

Don't reload the whole page. Just use ajax to reload the components that needs to be updated. jQuery is perfect for that.

Answer (score 0):

Use a setInterval with an ajax request. I'll update in 1 min with the script.

```
var divid = 'yourDivsId'

function createRequestObject() 
{
  var obj;
  var browser = navigator.appName;
    if(browser == "Microsoft Internet Explorer"){
    obj = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }else{
    obj = new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
  return obj;
}

function sendReq(req) 
{   
  http.open('get', req);
  http.onreadystatechange = handleResponse;
  http.send(null);
}

function handleResponse() 
{   
  if (http.readyState == 4)
  {
    var response = http.responseText;
    document.getElementById(divid).innerHTML=response;
  }
}


var http = createRequestObject();
setInterval('yourUrl', 30000); //or whatever time you want.
```

Should do the trick.